# How to handle Create/Edit pages in Nextjs, should I get the product in ServerSideProps or in the component

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, server-side-rendering, react-hook-form

I have a form where a user creates a product. This form uses react-hook-form to keep track of all form inputs. I'd like to reuse the form since the "Edit" page is the exact same form but with the fields filled out by data from the server.

What's the best practice is this case? Having a `ProductForm` component with an optional `product` prop? Or just copy pasting the form in two different files?

This is what I was thinking of:

`pages/product/create/index.tsx`

```js
export default function Create() {
  return <ProductForm />
}
```

`pages/product/create/edit.tsx`

```js
export default function Edit({id}: {id: number}) {
    const product = // Get the product with the id from the slug 
    return <ProductForm product={product} 
}


export async function getServerSideProps({ params }) { 
    return {
        props: { id: params.id }
    }
}
```

The second part of my question is what the best practice is for an Edit page to get the product from the server, `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps`. Should I be getting the product with the id from the slug inside one of those functions? So the edit would look something like this instead

`pages/product/create/edit.tsx`

```js
export default function Edit({product}: {product: Product}) {
    return <ProductForm product={product}
}


export async function getServerSideProps({ params }) {
    const product = // get product from slug id
    return {
        props: { product: product }
    }
}
```

New to Nextjs so any thoughts on this are appreciated

Comment: I don't think that there is an easy answer to this question. You can try to look at some principles like [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) which say that you should not repeat yourself, and the supposed benefit of that would be that you can work on both Edit and Create page at the same time. On the other hand, when the Edit page becomes different from Create pages, you might get a problem trying to make an overcomplicated general form component. My advice is to try one of the approaches and develop the intuitions on your own :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly what you should do.

Create a single form component, then import it into the create and edit pages.

On the edit page, get the product and pass it to the form as you are doing here.

Finally, there is some logic in the form component to determine create or edit mode, and then different behavior around handling submit or other stuff.